# x raised to an exponent mod n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Simple question, it's part of a much larger problem that I can do if I get this figured out. I looked all through my textbook and can't figure out how to find $x$ where $x^{294408} \not\equiv 1 (\mod 294409)$. I feel like this should be super simple but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem, or Euler's theorem may be good starting places.

Comment: Since 294409 factors, I believe none of its factors raised to any power could equal one.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-unit mod $294409$ works. For instance, $x=37$ or even the trivial example $x=294409$.

No unit mod $294409$ works:

Since $294409 = 37 \cdot 73 \cdot 109$, we have $U(294409) = U(37) \times U(73) \times U(109)$.

Therefore, $U(294409)$ has exponent $\operatorname{lcm}(36,72,108)=216$, that is, $x^{216} \equiv 1 \bmod 294409$ for all units mod $294409$.

Now $294408$ is a multiple of $216$ and so $x^{294408} \equiv 1 \bmod 294409$ for all units mod $294409$.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that a "unit" is an integer that is relatively prime to 294409.

Comment: BTW, this proves that $294409$ is a [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).